# Determining which jar did the .class come from in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I was debugging a certain thing in a maven project in `Eclipse IDE`. As usual when I `stepped into (F5)` a line, I reached a java class/file `Persistence.class`. I want to determine which `jar` did it come from.

**The reason** : There are two projects (existing) which have certain dependencies configured in pom.xml. I see two different source codes for the file - one of them gives the desired result while the other does not. I have tried looking for `persistence-api`, `ejb` etc. but didn't find any of them in the Maven dependencies shown in eclipse.

Hence, I want to `grep` the `poms` (of parent projects) to look for the jar.

**To Summarize**, Is there a view in Eclipse where I can see which jar a .class file is coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activate "Link with editor" in the Package Explorer (the double arrow) and press F3. Eclipse expands the class in a library. (Make sure, that the editor, that shows `Persistence.class` has the focus).

For the next step, assuming you use m2eclipse, open the pom editor and look at the Dependency Hierarchy Tab. That gives a first hint where the dependency comes from. It may be transitive.

Comment: Thank you. PS : In Juno it's with "Project Explorer".

Comment: Project Explorer is a different view. I personally prefer the Package Explorer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant I was not able to find the double arrow in the Package Explorer view. But I was wrong, it is very well there.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is to try opening the file using ctrl (cmd on mac) + t. This way you can open a type and on the bottom of the popup it shows you in which jar-file the class is found.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-shift-t to 'Open Type'.

Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)